# Join & Group By in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

executing code:

```
SELECT sr2.CLASSIFICATIONID, COUNT (sr2.CLASSIFICATIONID) FROM SR sr2
GROUP BY (CLASSIFICATIONID)
ORDER BY COUNT (sr2.CLASSIFICATIONID) desc;
```

all perfect. 
Trying to join extra table without any column selection:

```
SELECT sr2.CLASSIFICATIONID, COUNT (sr2.CLASSIFICATIONID) FROM SR sr2
LEFT JOIN CLASSSTRUCTURE cl on cl.CLASSSTRUCTUREID=sr2.CLASSIFICATIONID -- joining
GROUP BY (CLASSIFICATIONID)
ORDER BY COUNT (sr2.CLASSIFICATIONID) desc;
```

918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"
     *Cause:
     *Action:
     Error at Line: 3 Column: 11

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Group by sr2. classificationid

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I just needed id in GROUP BY

```
GROUP BY (sr2.CLASSIFICATIONID)
```

Comment: Simply write GROUP BY sr2.CLASSIFICATIONID, to avoid confusion. (It's not a function with an argument.)